# "frame_id" assignment

Tags: ros, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know the semantic behind the following `frame_id` assignment:

```
cloud.header.frame_id = "/map";
```

Which of the following (or both are) is correct:

1. We want to express our cloud values in the world(/map in this case) frame.
2. We want to express our cloud values with respect to the origin of the world(/map in this case) frame.

I just couldn't see the difference between those two, and at the moment, I presumed that they both carry the same semantic and effect.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28148/%22frame_id%22-assignment/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think 1. and 2. are exactly the same.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-22**:
Thanks a lot for the confirmation.